# Zero conf time synchronization in a LAN

Tags: time, lan, ntp, zeroconf, ptp

NTP seems to be the standard in time synchronization in networks where the NTP server is known, however I'm looking for a solution that would work with zero conf or avahi. In a way that devices recently added to the network could automatically discover the clock MASTER and source date and time from them, optionally they could become the master themselves.

I know that PTP works in that way, but it's made to share very precise timestamps, not time and date. Do you know of any solutions that would work in this case?

Comment: Could use DHCP Option 42, or Multicast (depending on the network layout & if the clients are configured for mcast as part of there build or deployment) Can you provide any more specific details. Are these clients you control or 3rd party/byo devices?